# Angular validation on form not working

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, form-submit

I have a form and I want to check if all the fields are valid or not.

Currently I am using four different methods. Nothing is working. Here is my plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/c4czI1W1fvXR4881SP1z?p=preview

Here are the methods I am using to check for validity

```
<button ng-click="my.$valid && validityCheck()">Update</button>
<div>myForm.$valid = {{myForm.$valid}}</div>
<span ng-show="myForm.$valid" style="color:green">Yippii!</span>
<span ng-show="myForm.$invalid" style="color:red">Not :(</span>
```

Comment: Where is the rest of the markup? Like the `<form>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plunkder code has few errors.

- Missing angular script tag
- ng-click should refer to myForm instead of my. `ng-click="myForm.$valid`
- Inject $scope to controller (or use **this**).  `function($scope){`

http://plnkr.co/edit/Twz9E9LnQ08IpweLARjG

Comment: Thanks. Frustratingly, I can't seem to reproduce my actual problem on the same plunker. In my application, neither $valid nor $invalid are triggering. No "yippii!" or "Not :(" messages are showing, and the space for myForm.$valid is blank. Do you know if it could be in another state that is neither $valid nor $invalid?

Comment: You want to use browser debugging tool (F12) to see the JavaScript error.

Comment: No errors using the browser debugging. I can see the status of my form by inspection:       <form name="myForm" class="ng-pristine ng-valid-maxlength ng-pending ng-invalid-required ng-valid-date ng-valid-firstvalidation" style="">

Comment: Parenthesis are missing. You need to use an editor. Here is the working code [http://plnkr.co/edit/1iteGVImQUtkkh94TKOh](http://plnkr.co/edit/1iteGVImQUtkkh94TKOh).

Comment: Found out that in my code I'm running into async validation errors as described here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11167 couldn't reproduce in a plunker but I accepted your answer because it solves the question here and fixes the plunker.